# 'No suitable conversion function' with cout

Tags: c++

When I was programming a simple "hello world" in a empty project, I kept getting the error in the message. I have read up on "pch.h" would fix it, but I previously didn't have this problem a while back. **Side note:** I am relatively new to c++.

[image: Error + Code]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Post a [mcve] as required please. Images of code aren't acceptable. Post formatted code!!

Comment: Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: "PCH" presumably stands for Precompiled Header. That is an optimization for faster builds, mostly useful when you have hundreds of files. You won't need it yet.

Comment: @Keith You've made a typo most of us have already done some day. I'll let you find it.

Comment: @MSalters Might not be needed, but is enabled by default by Visual Studio for new projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the definition of your `main` function. You need to add a parameter list. Either of these are valid:

```
int main() { .... }
int main(int argc, char** argv) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Project-Properties command (last command in the Project menu). And set the Precompiled Headers option like this for "All Configurations" and "All Platforms":

[image]

Also it's

```
int main()
{
  ...
```

and not

```
int main
{
  ...
```

Comment: In fact, the exact error OP gets comes from the missing parens.